# Get light sensor value in iOS without private API?

Tags: ios, sensors, iphone-privateapi, light, iokit

I need to get a concrete value from a sensor in **lux**. So no other substitute ways are appropriate for me, such as screen brightness.

It seems IOKit contains everything I need but it is private API and I will not be able to post my app on the app store.

So are there Apple-approved ways to get data from the light sensor? Or could you give a link to an official Apple documentation/official forum discussion where it is described that you can get light value via private API only?

Answer (score 0):

I opened video camera and parsed each frame's exif data dictionary to get brightness value.